# debug tkinter program with conflict pack/grid

Tags: tkinter

I shifted a section or my program from using grid to the pack geometry manager - I know that if you do it consistently so that you dont use both grid&back *at the same level* it is possible to do it.

Of course I did something wrong, but I cannot find the error since Tkinter doesnt seem to throw an exception in cases such as these: it simply sits running, without displaying the program interface.

There is some way to debug a program in the case of such conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place all of your geometry management code together, this becomes fairly easy to solve. I see many people who write code like this:

```
e = Entry(...)
e.grid(...)
f = Frame(...)
f.grid(...)
...
```

Instead, move all of your layout together, like this:

```
e = Entry(...)
f = Frame(...)
...
e.grid(...)
f.grid(...)
```

By doing that, it should quickly become obvious when you are mixing grid and pack together in the same master. Plus, it makes it much easier to refactor your code later when you need to add or remove additional widgets.

In a similar vein, I see people who write code like this:

```
class Something(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.pack(...)
```

A widget / widget class should never be responsible for packing/griding itself in its parent. If you change the geometry manager somewhere else in your code, this requires that you examine every other class to find which ones insert themselves into a container. Whatever code creates the children should be responsible for calling grid or pack on those children.

Finally, make sure that for any given container, all of the packing and griding happens in one place. Don't have pack or grid calls for a single container spread across two or more functions or classes.

If you refactor your code to follow those rules, it should be pretty easy to see where the problem is since the line of code that calls grid and the line of code that calls place will be in the same block of code.

If you are unable to make those changes, you have no choice but to start commenting out calls to pack (or grid; it doesn't matter, pick one) until your code starts to work. That should help you figure out which widget is the culprit.

Comment: very clear as usual, thank you. But I still dont understand why this is the only instance (that I know of) where in face of an obvious mistake, no error is generated at all